# ProgressBar and RenderTo not placing in the center

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am creating a progressBar dynamically while processing some work. It works but I am using the RenderTo method, and it doesn't appear in the center of the container.

here is my code

```
        var progressBar = Ext.create('Ext.ProgressBar', {
            renderTo: that.el,
            width: 305
        });
```

The width is correct, but its not rendered in the center of the container (that.el)

The container isn't a fixed size so I can't really add padding / margin as I would be unsure of the amount.

Anyone know a way around this ?

I am using an example of RenderTo, is there an alternative way to ensure that its added to the container and centered ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var progressBar = Ext.create('Ext.ProgressBar', {
        renderTo: that.el,
        style: 'margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto',
        width: 305
    });
```

This will probably work, but I'm unaware of the rest of your application's layout.

If you are full Extjs app, you should make "that.el" a container of some sort and handle this via layouts.

Ex: HBox layout with pack/align settings to center your items.

Comment: Thanks, yes, i managed to do it via layouts in the end. Thanks fro your help.